# projected cube map shader, white line between edges

Tags: html, three.js, shader

[image]

I'm trying to write a shader which renders a cube map / cube texture as an equirectangular projection.

The main part of this is done however I get white lines between the faces.

My methodology is:

1. Starting from UV ([0,1]x[0,1])
2. Transform to [-1,1]x[-1,1] and than to [-180,180]x[-90,90]
3. These are now long lat, which can be transformed into 3D (xyz)
4. Get the face they belong to, as well as their position within this face ([-1,1]x[-1,1])
5. Transform this face position to a UV within the cube texture

At first I thought the output of step 4 was wrong and that I was sampling from outside the texture, but even after multiplying the face coordinates by 1/2, I still get the white lines.

reference: https://codepen.io/coutteausam/pen/jOKKYYy

```
float max3(vec3 v) {
  return max(max(v.x, v.y), v.z);
}

vec2 sample_cube_map_1(vec3 xyz, out float faceIndex) {
  xyz /= length(xyz);

  float m = max3(abs(xyz));

  if (abs(xyz.x) == m) {
    faceIndex = sign(xyz.x);
    return xyz.yz / abs(xyz.x);
  }

  if (abs(xyz.y) == m) {
    faceIndex = 2. * sign(xyz.y);
    return xyz.xz / abs(xyz.y);
  }

  if (abs(xyz.z) == m) {
    faceIndex = 3. * sign(xyz.z);
    return xyz.xy / abs(xyz.z);
  }

  faceIndex = 1.0;
  return vec2(0., 0.);
}

vec2 sample_cube_map(vec3 xyz) {
  float face;

  vec2 xy = sample_cube_map_1(xyz, face);

  xy = (xy + 1.) / 2.; // [-1,1] -> [0,1]

  xy.x = clamp(xy.x, 0., 1.);
  xy.y = clamp(xy.y, 0., 1.);

  if (face == 1.) {
    // front
    xy += vec2(1., 1.);
  }
  else if (face == -1.) {
    //back
    xy.x = 1. - xy.x;
    xy += vec2(3., 1.);
  }
  else if (face == 2.) {
    // right
    xy.x = 1. - xy.x;
    xy += vec2(2., 1.);
  }
  else if (face == -2.) {
    // left
    xy += vec2(0., 1.);
  }
  else if (face == 3.) {
    // top
    xy = vec2(xy.y, 1. - xy.x);
    xy += vec2(1., 2.);
  }
  else if (face == -3.) {
    // bottom
    xy = xy.yx;
    xy += vec2(1., 0.);
  }
  else {
    xy += vec2(1., 0.);
  }

  return xy / vec2(4., 3.); // [0,4]x[0,3] -> [0,1]x[0,1]
}

// projects
//   uv:([0,1] x [0,1])
// to
//   xy:([ -2, 2 ] x [ -1, 1 ])
vec2 uv_2_xy(vec2 uv) {
  return vec2(uv.x * 4. - 2., uv.y * 2. - 1.);
}

// projects
//   xy:([ -2, 2 ] x [ -1, 1 ])
// to
//   longlat: ([ -pi, pi ] x [-pi/2,pi/2])
vec2 xy_2_longlat(vec2 xy) {
  float pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
  return xy * pi / 2.;
}

vec3 longlat_2_xyz(vec2 longlat) {
  return vec3(cos(longlat.x) * cos(longlat.y), sin(longlat.x) * cos(longlat.y), sin(longlat.y));
}

vec3 uv_2_xyz(vec2 uv) {
  return longlat_2_xyz(xy_2_longlat(uv_2_xy(uv)));
}

vec3 roty(vec3 xyz, float alpha) {
  return vec3(cos(alpha) * xyz.x + sin(alpha) * xyz.z, xyz.y, cos(alpha) * xyz.z - sin(alpha) * xyz.x);
}

varying vec2 vUv;
uniform sampler2D image;
uniform float time;
void main() {
  vec3 xyz = uv_2_xyz(vUv);

  xyz = roty(xyz, time);

  vec2 uv = sample_cube_map(xyz);

  vec4 texturePixel = texture2D(image, vec2(clamp(uv.x, 0., 1.), clamp(uv.y, 0., 1.)));
  gl_FragColor = texturePixel;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math behind your shader looks sound. However, you need to consider how texture sampling behaves when dealing with sub-pixels. Take a look at your source texture:

[image]

When you cross the boundary between `Top` to `Right`, your sampler will try to squeeze all the texture between magenta and teal into a single pixel. Since there's lots of white in that area, that squeezed pixel will be mostly white. Notice this doesn't happen between `Top` to `Front`, because there's no white area between those two faces. (Read: [mipmapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap#Mechanism) to see how textures behave when scaled down)

#### Solutions:

1. You might be able to sample the nearest full pixel, instead of trying to blend in between them, by turning off mipmapping. To do so, you can change the texture's [minification filter](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.minFilter) to linear filtering.

```js
const imgTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://i.imgur.com/tBzfYG5.png');
imgTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
```

The only downside is that you might get some hard edges along the boundaries.

[image]

2. If your project allows it, you could simply break up your texture into six images, then use the [cubemap method offered by Three.js](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cubemap#webgl_materials_cubemap_refraction)